# Limit access to specific dashboard in Google Monitoring

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-iam, google-cloud-monitoring

is it possible to create a GCP IAM user which has access only to a specific Google Monitoring dashboard? I figured it should be possible via [conditional role bindings](https://cloud.google.com/iam/docs/conditions-overview#supported-services), but monitoring dashboards are not a supported resource.

Are there other ways to achieve this?

Comment: There is an already feature request created in Public Issue Tracker to granular Stackdriver Permissions in Stackdriver Dashboards and Metrics. Please feel free to star it to get all the related updates on this issue.

https://issuetracker.google.com/147039227

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As mentioned by @Kamelia Y, at this time such feature is not available yet and there is a Feature Request in the public tracker: https://issuetracker.google.com/147039227

---

> There is not an available workaround for real-time separation of metrics.
>
> However, a project owner can achieve this separation via exporting their metrics manually and sending the appropriate information to the appropriate user. Here are two examples of exporting Stackdriver Monitoring metrics using App Engine/PubSub [1] or using Colab/Monitoring API [2]. Both use BigQuery to query the data and Cloud Scheduler to automate exporting the information.
>
> - [1] https://cloud.google.com/solutions/stackdriver-monitoring-metric-export
> - [2] https://medium.com/google-cloud/downsampling-and-exporting-stackdriver-monitoring-data-c3483e88a352